# Sorry, something went wrong The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, html, calculated-column-formula, button

```
=<a href=""https://www.google.co.in"" target=""_blank""><button>Edit</button></a>
```

Could you help me out with the error in here? it says "
Sorry, something went wrong

The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported. "

I am trying to create a button in a column which will navigate to a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set data type of column to Number and correct formula:

```
="<a href=""https://www.google.co.in"" target=""_blank""><button>Edit</button></a>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to create a `Button` in a SharePoint List View. This is not supported currently in SPO.

The correct syntax is below

```
="<a href='https://www.google.co.in' target='_blank'><button>Edit</button></a>"
```